# Finding std::boyer_moore_searcher

Tags: c++, stl, std, boyer-moore

I'd like to try using the [std::boyer_moore_searcher](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/boyer_moore_searcher) class. But I've run into two questions:

1. Where is it? I'm using Visual Studio 2019 but it reports *"namespace std has no member boyer_moore_searcher"*.
2. One of the issues with the Boyer Moore algorithm is that the jump table must be very large for Unicode characters. Can anyone tell me how the `boyer_moore_searcher` class deals with this?

Comment: Did you enable C++17? Because the doc you linked says it's a C++17 feature.

Comment: [this info page](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/cpp17-20-features-and-fixes-in-vs-2019/) suggests that VS 16.0 does include it, maybe you need to enable c++17 support ?

Comment: Can you clarify your second question? What do you mean by *jump table*?

Comment: You can try https://godbolt.org/ an online compiler to check. Be careful because the compiler switch for c++17 for msvc and the one for GCC/clang are different.

Comment: @Fureeish: The Boyer Moore Algorithm requires that a jump table is created so that the algorithm knows how many characters it can skip when it finds a mismatch.

Comment: Have you enabled C++17 features with the `/std:c++17` option or project properties?

Answer (score 2):

> One of the issues with the Boyer Moore algorithm is that the jump table must be very large for Unicode characters

This is not really an answer, but too long for a comment.

The "skip table" for Boyer-Moore needs to have an entry for every "character" in the pattern that you're searching for.

For `char`, the simplest (and fastest) way to do that is to have a 256-element array (and that's how the B-M algorithm was described in the original papers). But that's not a requirement; just an implementation detail.

Comment: This was mostly implied by the question. For `char`, a 256-element array is generally the implementation used. I was just curious if `boyer_moore_searcher` avoided creating a great big table for Unicode.

Comment: I suppose it's up to the implementation, but all the ones I've looked at use a `unordered_map` for anything other than plain old `char`

Answer (score 1):

This is the answer to the first question:

> Where is it? I'm using Visual Studio 2019 but it reports "namespace
>   std has no member boyer_moore_searcher".

`boyer_moore_searcher` is introduced in c++17 so to compile you need to enable c++17 option:
[MSVC Compile](https://godbolt.org/z/tS28t2) option `/std:c++17` or:

> propertie->C/C++->All Options->C++ Language Standard

.